# How can I set the preference variable $progressPreference inside of a session?

Tags: powershell, session, session-variables, runspace

I want to set `$progressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` inside of a session so that I can suppress the pipeline output of

> Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Get-Queue" command...

Similar to what's being done here
https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12405

Below is what I've tried with my code

```
$progressPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
$progressVariable = New-object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList 'progressPreference',$progressPreference,'silentlycontinue';
        
$session = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $uri -Authentication $authenticationType;
$session.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("progressPreference", "SilentlyContinue");  
$session.Runspace.InitialSessionState.Variables.Add($progressVariable);
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber -CommandName Set-AdServerSettings, Get-Mailbox, Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus, Get-MailboxDatabase, Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup, Get-ExchangeServer, Test-ServiceHealth, Get-Queue, Get-MailboxServer > $null;
$progressPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest:$true;
```

It apperas the SessionStateVariableEntry is working correctly as I see this

```
PS C:\Users\x\Documents> $progressVariable.Value
SilentlyContinue
PS C:\Users\x\Documents> $progressVariable.Name
progressPreference
```

I've also tried this

```
$session.Runspace.InitialSessionState.Variables.Add( [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('progressPreference', 'SilentlyContinue', 'Quells unnecessary messages'))
```

which gives an error message? I don't know why it errors?

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:1 char:1
>
> - $session.Runspace.InitialSessionState.Variables.Add( [System.Manageme ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>   ```

Comment: Where does `$progressVariable` come from?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I added that in the initial post, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for this:

```
Set-Variable ProgressPreference SilentlyContinue
```